# console error :Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') at handleClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, createcontext

In this page the user can login, but if the untilDate is bigger than the current date it should log out the user. The code runs fine 1/2 times, the other giving me the error on the title.
I am working with createContext for user login. This is the AuthContext file

```
import React from "react";
import { createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null,
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

export const AuthContext = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

const AuthReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN_START":
      return {
        user: null,
        loading: true,
        error: null,
      };
    case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
      return {
        user: action.payload,
        loading: false,
        error: null,
      };

    case "LOGOUT":
      return {
        user: null,
        loading: false,
        error: null,
      };
    case "LOGIN_FAILURE":
      return {
        user: null,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    case "UPDATE_USER_DATE":
      const updatedUser = { ...state.user };
      updatedUser.activeUntil = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        user: updatedUser,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, INITIAL_STATE);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.user));
  }, [state.user]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user: state.user,
        loading: state.loading,
        error: state.error,
        dispatch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

When the user clicks the login button, it runs the handleClick function:

```
  const handleClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_START" });
    let date = new Date().toJSON();
    let userdate = date;
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/auth/signin", credentials);
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: res.data.details });
      userdate = user.activeUntil;
      //do if date is <=current datem dispatch logout
    } catch (err) {
      if (userdate > date) {
        console.log("undefined data");
      } else {
        dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE", payload: err.response.data });
      }
    }

    if (userdate > date) {
      dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
      console.log("If you are seeing this your contract has expired");
    } else {
      // navigate("/myinfo");
    }
  };
```

The console error happens from this line `dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE", payload: err.response.data });`

Is there a way I can bypass this error or a different way I can write my code to make it work?
This is the full code of login page

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "../../context/AuthContext";
import {
  Container,
  FormWrap,
  FormContent,
  Form,
  FormInput,
  FormButton,
  Icon,
  FormH1,
  SpanText,
  IconWrapper,
  IconL,
} from "./signinElements";
import Image from "../../images/Cover.png";

const Login = () => {
  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({
    namekey: undefined,
    password: undefined,
  });
  /* */
  // to view current user in console
  const { user, loading, error, dispatch } = useContext(AuthContext);
  let msg;
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setCredentials((prev) => ({ ...prev, [e.target.id]: e.target.value }));
  };

  const handleClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_START" });
    let date = new Date().toJSON();
    let userdate = date;
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/auth/signin", credentials);
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: res.data.details });
      userdate = user.activeUntil;
      //do if date is <=current datem dispatch logout
    } catch (err) {
      if (userdate > date) {
        console.log("undefined data");
      } else {
        dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE", payload: err.response.data });
      }
    }

    if (userdate > date) {
      dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
      console.log("If you are seeing this your contract has expired");
    } else {
      // navigate("/myinfo");
    }
  };
  // console.log(user.activeUntil); //type to view current user in console

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <IconWrapper>
          <IconL to="/">
            <Icon src={Image}></Icon>
          </IconL>
        </IconWrapper>
        <FormWrap>
          <FormContent>
            <Form action="#">
              <FormH1>
                Sign in with the namekey and password written to you on your
                contract.
              </FormH1>
              <FormInput
                type="namekey"
                placeholder="Namekey"
                id="namekey"
                onChange={handleChange}
                required
              />
              <FormInput
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                id="password"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />

              <FormButton disabled={loading} onClick={handleClick}>
                Login
              </FormButton>
              <SpanText>{msg}</SpanText>
              {error && <SpanText>{error.message}</SpanText>}
              {error && (
                <SpanText>
                  Forgot namekey or password? Contact our support team +355 69
                  321 5237
                </SpanText>
              )}
            </Form>
          </FormContent>
        </FormWrap>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: Try logging `err`, see if it contains `response` object...

Comment: This just shows the same error, but console logged. thnx for the response, but i answered it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i was trying to call a localy stored user and 1 time it wasnt loaded and the other it was. Simply fixed it by changing the if statement to check directly in result details without having to look in local storage.

```
const [expired, setExpired] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_START" });

    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/auth/signin", credentials);
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: res.data.details });
      let date = new Date().toJSON();
      if (res.data.details.activeUntil < date) {
        dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
        console.log("Users contract has expired");
        setExpired(!expired);
      } else {
        navigate("/myinfo");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE", payload: err.response.data });
    }
  };
```